# Set AWS Profile in PowerShell is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I've set AWS Profile in Powershell and when I run get EC2 instance it is still picking up EC2 instance Role instead of the Profile I've set:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Profile | ADMIN-1122333445566 |
| Instance Details to be fetched | i-abcxyz |
| Region of Instance to be fetched | eu-west-1 |
| Instance Which I'm running the commands from | i-786456xyz |
| Account which I'm running the commands from | 9988776655 |

PowerShell 7.4.1

PS /home/admin> $env:AWS_PROFILE="ADMIN-1122333445566"

PS /home/admin> aws configure list

| Name | Value | Type | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| profile | ADMIN-1122333445566 | env | ['AWS_PROFILE', 'AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE'] |
| access_key | ******************** | sso |  |
| secret_key | ******************** | sso |  |
| region | us-east-1 | imds |  |

PS /home/admin> Get-EC2Instance -InstanceId i-abcxyz -region eu-west-1

Get-EC2Instance: You are not authorized to perform this operation. **User: arn:aws:sts::9988776655:assumed-role/user-devops/i-786456xyz** is not authorized to perform: ec2:DescribeInstances because no identity-based policy allows the ec2:DescribeInstances action

PS /home/admin> Write-Output $env:AWS_PROFILE

ADMIN-1122333445566

PS /home/admin> aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-abcxyz --region eu-west-1

AWS CLI gives me the output. so somehow PowerShell is not picking up the Profile. I tried Get-STSCallerIdentity and it is showing the Instance Profile.

Is there anyway to force my PowerShell Session to use the AWS Profile instead of Instance Role?

Comment: AWS cli works fine:

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to use AWS Tool command to set a profile.

```
Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey <AccessKeyId> -SecretKey <SecretAccessKey> -ProfileName ADMIN-1122333445566
```

This will load the credentials contained in the specified profile and sets them active for all commands in the current shell.
By default, AWS Tools for PowerShell stores these credentials in the AWS credentials file located at `$HOME\.aws\credentials` on Windows.

Comment: I tried the command, and it threw an error "Set-AWSCredential: Assembly AWSSDK.SSOOIDC could not be found or loaded" and when I try Get-STSCallerIdentity it is showing arn:aws:sts::9988776655:assumed-role/user-devops/i-786456xyz

Comment: Try also specifying -AccessKey <AccessKeyId> -SecretKey <SecretAccessKey> along with ProfileName

Comment: I'm using SSO, so I don't have credentials file created